# Merge parameters for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a loop in Python which sequentially imports CSV files, assigns them to a temporary DataFrame object and then attempts to merge/concact them to a 'master' DataFrame. The code is below:

```
for csv_path in csv_paths:
    df = pd.read_csv(''+csv_path+'')
    df = df.set_index('Player')
    if len(MLS_Stats) == 0:
        MLS_Stats = pd.concat([MLS_Stats,df])
    else:
        MLS_Stats = pd.merge(MLS_Stats, df, how="outer",left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

The MLS_Stats DF is initially empty, which is the reasoning for the if loop, since I don't think you can merge a DF with an empty DF.

For each merge, I want build the DataFrame by including any new uniquely indexed rows and new columns, but exclude overlapping columns. The above code currently includes the overlapping columns with _x and _y suffixes.

I know there must be something I'm not understanding, because this doesn't seem like an uncommon situation.

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Or the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: It's including the overlapping columns...I'm wondering now if the comnbine_first method is what I need?

Comment: Why not make a list of dataframes `df_list = [df1,df2,df3]`, and then concatenate them all at the same time `MLS_Stats = pd.concat(df_list)`?

Comment: Curious -- is MLS Major League Soccer? If so, what kind of analysis are you doing? (I once played around looking at MLS salaries.)

Comment: @Aman, I'm doing a team project for a class. One of my classmates has a brother who plays, so that's primarily why we're doing the project based on MLS data. So far we're trying to find whether correlations exist between salary and things like goals, assists, and # of google search results to attempt to measure popularity. Sadly there has been very little correlation, probably because of the complexity involved in evaluating a soccer player's value. Also because most players are paid sh!t anyways :)

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong Would love to see that analysis if you end up posting it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter duplicate rows with `drop_duplicates`, and select to join only columns that are not yet present.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data0 = """\
index,A,B
a,1,2
a,1,2
b,3,4
c,5,6
"""

data1 = """\
index,A,C
a,7,8
d,9,10
"""

df = pd.DataFrame()
columns = []
for data in [data0, data1]:
    frame= pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0).drop_duplicates()
    frame = frame.ix[:, frame.columns - columns]
    if len(frame):
        df = df.join(frame, how='outer') if len(df) else frame

print df
```

results in:

```
        A   B   C
index
a       1   2   8
b       3   4 NaN
c       5   6 NaN
d     NaN NaN  10
```

Comment: Although this seems like it'd work with the above code, I ended up using the 'combine_first' method to accomplish what I wanted.